# How to create msi for wpf in specific culture

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, installation

I have an application in English build with C# and WPF, and I use resource file (.resx) to translate the UI into my language. And add this line to the app.config

```
<add key="CurrentCulture" value="vi-VN" />
```

Everything is fine if I run from code. However, when I use wix to create .msi and install, run from that everything is reverted back to English.

I think it has something to do with culture setup somewhere in the code. But, if I change AssemblyCulture of the app, it crashes. I look around, and couldn't find anything that can fix it. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you in advance, and sorry if I make any mistakes. English is not my native language.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a localization file, maybe a dll or similar. Run your application from within Visual Studio, go to **`Debug`** **`=>`** **`Windows`** **`=>`** **`Modules`**. Look at what modules are loaded and in use by the application. Determine what is missing in your deployment folder. You can also just diff the build output folder and the installation folder first - that is usually enough. I don't do WPF localization, how have you implemented it? Did you create your own resource file copy?

Comment: Yes. For example, just create Labels.resx and another Labels.vi-VN.resx, with the same keys, just change the values to the appropriate language. And in app.config, just add the line in my post. And it changes to the new language.